# Can't get object constructed

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, each

I have a problem I'm not able to solve, maybe you guys could help me!

I got a few checkboxes. I need the values of the checked ones on a button click. That works so far. Now i need to construct some kind of object/array with this infos.

The Construct in the end has to look this way:

```
[{"ID-Number":"1","ID-Data":"ABCD1234"},{"ID-Number":"2","ID-Data":"DEFG5678"}]
```

The "ABCD1234" and "DEFG5678" are the Values of the checked checkboxes. The "ID-Number" should be counted one up for each checked checkbox entry, starting with 1.

I thought I might have to build one array first, then one array for each "entry" and then add those arrays to the main-array?

My code looks something like this:

```
listToSubmit = [];

i = "0";

$("input[name=mycheckboxgroup]:checked").each(function () {

    newEntry = [];

    newEntry['ID-Number'] = i++;
    newEntry['ID-Data'] = $(this).val();

    listToSumbit.push(newEntry);

});

console.log(listToSubmit)
```

Thanks for any help getting this to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the correct index, you can loop all of the checkboxes:

```js
listToSubmit = []
elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=mycheckboxgroup]")

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
  if (elements[i].checked)
    listToSubmit.push( { 'ID-Number' : i + 1 + '', 'ID-Data' : elements[i].value } )

console.log(JSON.stringify(listToSubmit))
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' name='mycheckboxgroup' value='ABCD1234' checked \>
<input type='checkbox' name='mycheckboxgroup' value='DEFG5678' checked \>
<input type='checkbox' name='mycheckboxgroup' value='XYZ90' \>
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple of problems with your code:

- you're doing `listToSumbit.push(newEntry)`, which should be `listToSubmit.push(newEntry)`
- starting with `i = "0"` is a bit weird and could cause issues - try `i = 0` instead.

With the typo, I strongly recommend using a good linter in your IDE - eslint is great. It'll help catch these bugs straight off.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out those typos. Now I got ahead with it :) One last thing is how can I get the output as needed now? And why is it outputting the console.log two times in the console (has two entries)? I need this to be "stringified" like in the example in the end...

Comment: Try `JSON.stringify( listToSubmit )` to get a string version.